# Can I get the Email ID before Sign In using Firebase - Google SignIn in website?

Tags: firebase, web, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I'm using `Firebase Google SignIn` to authenticate users. But I need to get the Email Id of user before SignIn operation is performed. Is there any way to get the email id before `signin-success callback` is performed ?

Answer (score 0):

It will return the user data on "GoogleAuthProvider". Hope the below code helps you.
Refer - https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/GoogleAuthProvider

```
loginWithGmail() {
  return from(
  this.afauth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider())
  .then((data) => {
  if (!data.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser) {
    return this.updateUserDetailsOnLogin(data);
  } else {
  return this.updateUserDetailsOnSignup(data, data.user.displayName);
  }
  }).catch((err) => {
    return err;
  })
  );
}
```